# Select an entire range that is blank based off of the column next to it

Tags: excel

I have a column in Excel that I need to select all in the range in order to make a change. The issue is that the column will usually populate blanks in the rows. The column next to it however will never show blanks, we will call this column "No Blanks".

The Selection code I use currently is below, first I Filter out an error then I go to the specific column needed and go to the last row and select up to the 2nd to first row in the column. The issue is that this row is always blank so it only goes to the first row in the column right away and doesn't make any changes.

Is there a way to make the selection for "Blanks Column", based off of the data in the column "No Blanks" which always has data and therefore can always be selected to the end of the sheet where data is?

```
Sub FindErrorAndCorrect()

Dim FieldName As Range
Dim rng As Range, res As Variant, lrow As Long
Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1)
res = Application.Match("Errors", rng, 0)
Dim rLastCell As Range

'Finds the Specific Error'
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=res, Criteria1:="*-Error 1*"
'Only Shows rows that have something that matches the filter criteria
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, res).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, res), Cells(lrow,res)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Set FieldName = Range("A1:BZ1").Find("Blanks Column")
'If field isnt present shows message
    If FieldName Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Field Name was not found."
Else
Set rLastCell = LastCell(ActiveSheet, FieldName.Column)
'Changes the Selection
Range(Cells(2, FieldName.Column), Cells(rLastCell.Row, FieldName.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "35" '<------Make Change Here
'Changes the Color of the fields changed to Yellow
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
End With
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is of any help.  Say we have:

[image]

and we want to high-light only those cells in column **A** that are:

- empty
- have a non-empty neighbor

This macro:

```
Sub markEmpty()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("B1:B" & N)
    r.Offset(0, -1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 100)
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just want to select those cells in colum A, and then have the rest of the code play out, which is make a change and then highlight. This is also based off of column name and the range can always be different.